How to reload the current page with a temporary table view in Business Central?
I'm trying to populate a Temporary Table to reload the current page with the records of the temporary table:
pageextension 60008 "Assembly Orders PL" extends "Assembly Orders"//902
{
    trigger OnOpenPage()
    var
        AssemblyOrders: Page "Assembly Orders";
        OriginalHeader: Record "Assembly Header";
        AssemblyHeaderTemp: Record "Assembly Header" temporary;
    begin
        if not RunOnce then begin
            AssemblyHeaderTemp.Reset();
            AssemblyHeaderTemp.DeleteAll();
            OriginalHeader.SetRange("Document Type", Rec."Document Type"::Order);
            if OriginalHeader.FindSet() then
                repeat                                    
                    // Check if the No. Series have extra security
                    if LMEnsamblado.ImplicaSeguridad(OriginalHeader."No. Series") then begin
                        // If the No. Series has extra security, we check if the current user has rights
                        if LMEnsamblado.TienePermisosLM(OriginalHeader."Item No.") then begin                        
                            AssemblyHeaderTemp.Init();                            
                            AssemblyHeaderTemp.TransferFields(OriginalHeader);
                            AssemblyHeaderTemp.CalcFields(Comment);
                            AssemblyHeaderTemp.CalcFields("Reserved Quantity");
                            AssemblyHeaderTemp.CalcFields("Reserved Qty. (Base)");
                            AssemblyHeaderTemp.CalcFields("Assemble to Order");
                            AssemblyHeaderTemp.CalcFields("Rolled-up Assembly Cost");
                            AssemblyHeaderTemp.Insert();
                        end;
                    end;
                until OriginalHeader.Next() = 0;

            CurrPage.Close();
            AssemblyOrders.SetRecord(AssemblyHeaderTemp);
            AssemblyOrders.SetTableView(AssemblyHeaderTemp);
            AssemblyOrders.SetRunOnce();
            AssemblyOrders.Run();
            CurrPage.Update();
        end;
    end;

    procedure SetRunOnce()
    begin
        RunOnce := true
    end;

    var
        LMEnsamblado: Codeunit "LM Ensamblado";
        RunOnce: Boolean;
}

That code it's not making any difference because I'm still getting 91 records, I'm debugging and some entries are not inserted to the table but still exists in the page list...
I've also tried with AssemblyHeaderTemp.Copy(OriginalHeader); instead of AssemblyHeaderTemp.TransferFields(OriginalHeader); but I see no difference.
How can I reload the current page with a temporary table view?

Anything after the CurrPage.Close();  shouldn't be executed anyway.

Reopening a page from itself is not a good idea. If you want to hide some records then add a filter to the filtergroup that user can't clear. Also consider using SetAutoCalcfields(), it's more performant.

Hi @MakSim thank you, how can I hide some records? Adding a filter if the user cannot clear it is valid. Could you post it as an answer with a little example so I can also vote up and at least give some rep in return? :) thank you again :)

Solved by using Mark(true) and MarkedOnly(true):
pageextension 60008 "Assembly Orders PL" extends "Assembly Orders"//902
{
    trigger OnOpenPage()
    begin
        Rec.SetRange("Document Type", Rec."Document Type"::Order);
        if Rec.FindSet() then
            repeat                                    
                if LMEnsamblado.ImplicaSeguridad(Rec."No. Series") then begin
                    if LMEnsamblado.TienePermisosLM(Rec."Item No.") then begin
                        Rec.Mark(true);
                    end;
                end else
                    Rec.Mark(true);
            until Rec.Next() = 0;
        Rec.MarkedOnly(true);
    end;

    var
        LMEnsamblado: Codeunit "LM Ensamblado";
}

It's the simplest method I've found out :)

This will work. I think it is a simplies method, not optimal in regards to performance thoug.

As @MakSim pointed out in the answers already reopening a page from itself is not a good idea. Instead use the FilterGroup and add the filters to it. This blog post by ZHU got you covered: https://yzhums.com/8427/
In the following example you can see what this could look like. Please note, however, that this is by no means a very scalable or good example. With larger databases, you will reach the limits of the SetFilter. Perhaps you can also let us know the logic of the user rights check. Then we can try to optimise this even further.
trigger OnOpenPage()
begin
    FilterRecords();
end;

local procedure FilterRecords()
begin
    Rec.FilterGroup(2);
    Rec.SetRange("Document Type", Rec."Document Type"::Order);
    Rec.SetFilter("No.", GetRecordsFilter());
    Rec.FilterGroup(0);
end;

local procedure GetRecordsFilter() NumbersFilter: Text
var
    OriginalHeader: Record "Assembly Header";
    AssemblyOrders: Page "Assembly Orders";
    FirstRecord: Boolean;
begin
    FirstRecord := true;
    OriginalHeader.SetRange("Document Type", Rec."Document Type"::Order);
    if OriginalHeader.FindSet() then
        repeat
            // Check if the No. Series have extra security
            if LMEnsamblado.ImplicaSeguridad(OriginalHeader."No. Series") then begin
                // If the No. Series has extra security, we check if the current user has rights
                if LMEnsamblado.TienePermisosLM(OriginalHeader."Item No.") then begin
                    if FirstRecord then begin
                        NumbersFilter += OriginalHeader."No.";
                        FirstRecord := false;
                    end else
                        NumbersFilter += '|' + OriginalHeader."No.";
                end;
            end;
        until OriginalHeader.Next() = 0;
end;

Another thing I want to mention is that the PageVariable.SetRecord() procedure does not use temporary records and is meant to display a single record when the page list is opened (see: Page.SetRecord(var Record) Method | Parameters). So if you would run into this scenario again, make sure to replace
AssemblyOrders.SetRecord(AssemblyHeaderTemp);
AssemblyOrders.SetTableView(AssemblyHeaderTemp);
AssemblyOrders.Run();

by
Page.Run(Page::"Assembly Orders", AssemblyHeaderTemp);

Perhaps using the SecurityFilter might make sense when checking your specific user rights (see: Record.SecurityFiltering([SecurityFilter]) Method and Using Security Filters)
